# Retrieve Entities based on logic

Tags: java, xodus

I have this code:

```
EntityIterable iterable = null;
                    if(authId== null) {
                        iterable = txn.find(entityType, "publicRead", true).skip(skip).take(limit);
                    } else {
                        iterable = txn.getAll(entityType)
                                .union(txn.find(entityType, "read(" + authId+ ")", true))
                                .union(txn.find(entityType, "publicRead", false))
                                .union(txn.find(entityType, "publicRead" ,true)).skip(skip).take(limit);
                    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to get results based on this logic:

- If `publicRead` is true then return all Entities that have the property
  set to true (trivia)

The problems is this:

- If `authId` is present then retrieve all Entities with `publicRead = false && read(userIdauthIdRoleId) = true` or `publicRead = true && read(authId) = true`

How can this be achieved with the Xodus API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in the following way:

```
EntityIterable publicRead = txn.find(entityType, "publicRead", true);

EntityIterable result;

if (authId == null) {
    result = publicRead;
} else {
    result =
        txn.getAll(entityType).minus(publicRead).intersect(txn.find(entityType, "read(userIdauthIdRoleId)", true))
        .union(publicRead.intersect(txn.find(entityType, "read(" + authId + ")", true)));
}

result = result.skip(skip).take(limit);
```

Comment: Hello @vyacheslav-lukianov Thanks!